# SQL Server Convert int to Datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to convert some data that has datatype `int`. However when I tried to convert `200` into year, it throws an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Code:

```
declare @MonthStart datetime,
        @Day int = 1,
        @Month int = 5,
        @Year int = 200 /*gives me an error if I input this but when I tried 2016 the code works fine*/

set @MonthStart =  Cast(@Month as varchar(10)) +'-'+ Cast(@Day as varchar(10))+'-'+Cast(@Year as varchar(10))

select @MonthStart
```

I don't know what's the problem on this. Maybe the `datetime` won't accept this kind of format `200-05-01` as a date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error pointed out, you have an out-of-range value. The minimum value for `DATETIME` is:

```
1753-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

What you're tring to convert is below the minimum, thus the error.

---

As commented by marc_s:

> And if you're on SQL Server 2008 or newer, you can get around this
>   problem by using `DATETIME2(3)` instead of `DATETIME`. This new datatype
>   doesn't have those "artificial" range limitations as the old one did.

Comment: And if you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, you can get around this problem by using `DATETIME2(3)` instead of `DATETIME`. This new datatype doesn't have those "artificial" range limitations as the old one did.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime2` instead of `datetime`.  It supports dates of 1-1-0001 or later.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx